# How can I schedule background tasks for delayed execution in IBM 4690 OS?

Tags: scheduling

Background applications can be configured to start automatically when a controller is powered on, or when the controller assumes the role of master/file server. Is it possible to schedule activation based on different criteria? Eg running a background task daily at a specified hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through several manuals and many searches on the web, I have to say I don't think it's possible. You could either setup another server to remote in and run a command or...

This company sells a solution to schedule and replay tasks:

http://www.torexretailna.com/rssweb.nsf/b4e2f944ba463fe98825712b000005a8/$FILE/Torex%20Retail%20AutomatedOperator.doc

HTML:
http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:qgmIqxlKfyAJ:www.torexretailna.com/rssweb.nsf/b4e2f944ba463fe98825712b000005a8/%24FILE/Torex%2520Retail%2520AutomatedOperator.doc+automated+tasks+ibm+4690&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Manuals referenced:

User Guide:
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/retail/pubs/sw/opsys/4690/ver5r2/bsf1_UG_mst.pdf

Programmer's Guide:
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/retail/pubs/sw/opsys/4690/ver5r2/bsi1_PG_mst.pdf

Planning and config:
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/retail/pubs/sw/opsys/4690/ver5r2/bse1_PIC_mst.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:
- Launch a program trought ftp commands (adxquote) 
- Code a background app that start other programs based on a criteria.